# iOS app firewall content filtering

Tags: objective-c, ios, filter, html5-video, firewall

We have a native iOS app that is used by schools across the country. We've had some instances where the user isn't able to access remote video content. I don't really have any details about the school networks that seem to be blocking our video content so I guess my question is more general in nature.

Is it possible for certain firewalls to block remote mov, m4v, mp4, mp3 content that is being requested from within a native iOS app? As far as we can tell the schools that are having trouble receiving video and audio content within the app are able to access the same content when browsing with Safari. This leads me to believe that the firewall might be setup with a different set of rules for the native app vs. Safari.

I can probably provide more detailed information but I'm just not sure what it is I need to know in order to trouble shoot this problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the content retrieved from a server with an iOS app is accessed in the same way a browser does. Over the HTTP protocol. You can embed the video in the application as a fallback when it cannot be retrieved if you have to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately we have around 4GB of content so including it in the app is not a possibility so accessing over HTTP is our only option. Do you know if it's possible to have a different set of content filters for the iOS apps than what's in place for browsing with Safari or other web browser? If they're both using HTTP I would think the rules would be the same but that doesn't seem to be the case. We have customers that are able to access the videos through our HTML5 web app but not through our native iOS app on iPad/iPhone.

Comment: I suspect that is because of the extension of the file that it is getting from iOS. I would imagine that on the server iOS is getting a m4v or mov via HTTP and this is different than what the browser is getting. You could change your native app to load the HTML5 video in a WebView that way you hit the same file...

Comment: basically the idea is to make the request look no different than if it came from a browser. It is also possible that the browser is going through a proxy server and your iOS app is not.